# How to set fixed width of td within a fixed table layout

Tags: css

I have been unsuccessful trying to set a width of the first td/th cell within a table using table layout fixed

https://jsfiddle.net/4m5vf9zb/101/

```
#standings  {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#division00,#division01 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.standingslogo {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
th.ficonname{
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `colgroup` element to set the width of your columns.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/4m5vf9zb/102/

Comment: any css only method , i dont have authorization to edit this html

Answer (score 1):

The only CSS way to solve this is to remove the fixed layout.

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

```
#standings  {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Why?**

Because in a fixed layout, the column's width is defined by the measures of the cells in the first row. The other rows are ignored:

[*From MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout):

> **fixed**
>   Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

Comment: ok thanks, was using the fixed table layout to scale the images down for the .standinglogos , as there is no other way to do this